# Why don't my Defiant LED Security Lights work anymore?

Tags: light, motion-sensor

I have 3 pairs (2 at the front and one at the back); the back one still works (there is a blinking red light when the switch that controls it is on) but the two at the front do not come on (no blinking red light...also there was never a light fixture switch that controlled them anyhow). Could it be the motion sensors batteries are dead and need to be replaced (and if so how?), or that the lightbulbs need to be replaced and if so how? Thanks so much in advance for advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: No "attached photo". Motion sensor batteries? Typical (but not all) will use one of several methods (neutral, leak through lights, etc.) to get power without having to use batteries. But if they have batteries, then yes they likely need to be replaced. Bulbs - odd they would all go out at once but depends on the bulb type and usage. **Pictures and model numbers will help a lot.**

Comment: Details like the model number of the lights would help are the lamps part of the fixture or are they replaceable. The only motion sensor lights I have seen that use batteries are solar at least with mains power connected. More info is needed but the LED driver has probably failed.

Comment: I just realized you said no red light on the front ones did you check the breaker panel since there s no switch (that is unusual)

Comment: If they are line (AC) powered, there's usually no battery associated with the motion sensor. As Ed said, check the breaker for power to them. Most "LED security lights" don't have replaceable bulbs, and if somehting goes, it's usually the driver for the LEDs, not the LEDs themselves.

Comment: If they are LED lights, if the driver has gone, you probably can't replace that. If it's an LED panel instead of a standard screw in bulb, you probably can't replace that. However, all we can do is guess since we don't have much to go on, like a model number or even the promised picture.

Comment: I would expect LED security lights to use 12 volt DC (constant-voltage)  internally for both sensor and lights, because 12 volt motion sensors are mass produced commodities on Alibaba, and so are LED heads.   12 volt motion sensors are half the cost of 120V ones. So I expect LED motion sensors lights would be super hackable, including replacing the motion sensor.

Comment: @EdBeal et al I have added the pics; please forgive me for not adding them the first time. I am still at a loss. Is there a way to confirm these aren't battery operated? (I can't quite find an opening to check). If it's the driver, what do you suggest as to how I replace the driver? And is the best way to confirm by reseting the breaker?

Comment: What happens when you slide the top switch to "TEST" on the non-working ones vs the working ones? In that last pic, there's a pretty significant line to the right of the "control panel" that appears to go all the way around the sensor unit. I'd try squeezing the sides of the sensor unit. If it moves at all, that's probably a cover that comes off to reveal the electronics & battery. Squeeze & wiggle gently, and maybe lay down a drop cloth on the ground to catch the battery as it may just fall out if it's a coin battery.

Comment: I would pull the screw and verify the power. It looks like a rubber plug above the 180 sensor. Since no red light I would believe it is switched somewhere else or a breaker tripped since both quit. If there are electrical connections as I suspect a non contact tester may be helpful.  No power a breaker or switch has changed state or off. I have been amazed by the locations I have found switches in the past. More likely lack of power since they both went out at the same time it could be a GFCI outlet that feeds them from a closet or other location once power is verified the hunt starts.

Comment: Okay roger that Ed Beal. I will give that a try (if I can find my breaker in this house...I've looked everywhere, but will keep looking). I will also check for battery @FreeMan

Comment: It turns out it was a wire in my switchbox that controlled those lights and the wire was unplugged. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted in a comment by the OP more than a year ago. Posting here for discoverability and to get this closed out.

> It turns out it was a wire in my switchbox that controlled those lights and the wire was unplugged. Thanks so much.